# CPU Resource pool with and without hyperthreading in vmware esx/esxi

Tags: vmware-esxi, intel, resources, central-processing-unit, hyperthreading

VMWare ESX/ESXI running with AMD 12core @2.2GHz. Intel 6core @2.4GHz

In resource pool, with amd cpu I should see 26.4GHz available. Now it's interesting what will be shown with Intel CPU? Am I gonna get 14.4GHz resource pool or 28.8GHz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will see 6 x 2.4GHz (14.4GHz). The Intel HyperThreaded CPU cores do not count towards the CPU resources.

Here's an example with a single quad-core Intel 2.26GHz CPU:

[image]

And the socket information:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know. Offtopic question but does vmware use or take advantages of hyperthreading? I am choosing between intel 6core and amd 12core. Intel should be faster but amd will provide higher resource pool. Not sure if higher resource pool will overtake intel performance with lower resource pool.

Comment: Yes, VMWare does take advantage of HyperThreading on Intel CPUs. It's aware and is intelligent about scheduling on physical versus logical cores. I think your choice is going to be a function of how heavily your load your system, but I can say that my VMWare clusters running on Intel 55xx and 56xx-series CPUs run out of RAM well before running out of CPU resources. So I tend to stick with Intel for the higher clock speeds and a greater selection of stepping speeds within the server line I prefer (HP).